# React dnd kit drag drop issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-dnd, dnd-kit

I am new to drag and drop in react and I am trying a simple example to move items from a list to a canvas. I am using dnd-kit, material UI and type script. Here is my code

App.tsx

```
import { ItemProp } from "./types";
import MainScreen from "./components/MainScreen";

function App() {
  const items: ItemProp[] = [
    { id: "1", name: "Save" },
    { id: "2", name: "Execute" },
    { id: "3", name: "Create" },
  ];
  return <MainScreen initialItems={items} />;
}

export default App;
```

MainScreen.tsx

```
import { ItemArrayProp } from "../types";
import { ItemProp } from "../types";
import { useState } from "react";
import ListComponent from "./ListComponent";

import { DragOverlay, useDroppable } from "@dnd-kit/core";

import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import {
  DndContext,
  closestCenter,
  KeyboardSensor,
  PointerSensor,
  useSensors,
  useSensor,
  TouchSensor,
} from "@dnd-kit/core";
import CanvasComponent from "./CanvasComponent";

function MainScreen({ initialItems }: ItemArrayProp) {
  const [canvasItems, setCanvasItems] = useState<ItemProp[]>([]);
  const handleDrop = (event: any) => {
    const { over, active } = event;
    console.log(event);

    if (active && over) {
      const itemId = active.id;
      const item = initialItems.find((item) => item.id === itemId);
      console.log(item);

      if (item) {
        setCanvasItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, item]);
        console.log(canvasItems);
      }
    }
  };
  const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor),
    useSensor(TouchSensor),
    useSensor(KeyboardSensor)
  );

  return (
    <DndContext
      sensors={sensors}
      collisionDetection={closestCenter}
      onDragEnd={handleDrop}
    >
      <div>
        <h1>List</h1>
        <ListComponent items={initialItems} />
        <h1>Canvas</h1>

        <CanvasComponent items={canvasItems} />
      </div>
    </DndContext>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

ListComponent.tsx

```
import { ItemArrayProps } from "../types";
// import { List } from "@mui/material";
import ListDraggableItem from "./ListDraggableItem";

function ListComponent({ items }: ItemArrayProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ListDraggableItem key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListComponent;
```

ListDraggableItem.tsx

```
import { useDraggable } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import { DraggableItemProps } from "../types";
import { ListItemText, ListItem } from "@mui/material";

function ListDraggableItem({ item }: DraggableItemProps) {
  const { listeners, setNodeRef, attributes, transform } = useDraggable({
    id: item.id,
  });
  const style = transform
    ? {
        transform: `translate3d(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px, 0)`,
      }
    : undefined;

  return (
    <ListItem ref={setNodeRef} {...attributes} {...listeners} style={style}>
      <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
    </ListItem>
  );
}

export default ListDraggableItem;
```

Overall, the Drag works, but I do not see it dropping into the canvas. There is some weird behavior as well. Second time I click on the list, I can see the previously dropped item.  I have a sandbox link here with my code https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-jang-0hd5s2?file=/src/App.tsx

Please help